# jQuery easySlider not working in ASP.NET using C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am having trouble getting the jQuery easySlider working. Can anyone find where I am going wrong?

```
<%@ Page Title="About  me" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="About.aspx.cs" Inherits="About" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/easySlider1.7.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#slider").easySlider();
    });
</script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>About me</h2>

    <p> Info on the user logged in.</p>
    <p>Name:</p>
    <p>Student number:</p>
    <p>If information displayed is incorrect, please email with corect details.</p>

    <div id="slider">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="Styles/images/slider/01.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="Styles/images/slider/02.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="Styles/images/slider/03.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="Styles/images/slider/04.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="Styles/images/slider/05.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

The jQuery files name and paths are all correct. I can't seem to find where else the problem might be.

**EDIT**
When the page is rendered, this is what the HTML code looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">


<head>
<title>About  me</title>

<link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/easySlider1.7.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.js" ></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='Scripts/jquery.cookie.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='Scripts/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.7.min.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#accordion-menu').dcAccordion({

            eventType: 'click',

            autoClose: true,

            saveState: true,

            disableLink: true,

            showCount: false,

            speed: 'slow'

        });

        $('#slider').easySlider();

    });

</script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="header">

        <div class="headerLogo"><img src="Styles/images/reading_uni_logo.gif" /></div>

        <div class="loginDisplay">Welcome <span id="HeadLoginName">Username</span>! | Logout</div>

        <div class="news">

        </div>

        <div class="polls"><span id="question">Do you think the library should be open 24 hours?</span>

        <br /><a href="Polls.aspx">See more</a></div>     

    </div>

    <div id="addGadgetButton">Add gadget</div>


    <div id="menu">

        <ul class="menu" id="accordion-menu">

        <li><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>

        <li class="current-parent"><a href="GettingStarted.aspx">Getting Started</a></li>

        <li><a href="#">Apps</a>

            <ul>

                <li><a href="#">Apps 1</a></li>

                <li><a href="#">Apps 2</a></li>

                <li><a href="#">Apps 3</a></li>

            </ul>

        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Social</a>

            <ul>

                <li><a href="#">Social 1</a></li>

                <li><a href="#">Social 2</a></li>

                <li><a href="#">Social 3</a></li>

                <li><a href="#">Social 4</a></li>

            </ul>

        </li>

        <li><a href="About.aspx">About me</a></li>

        </ul>

   </div>

    <div id="main">  

    <h2>

        About me

    </h2>

    <p> Info on the user logged in.</p>

    <p>Name:</p>

    <p>Student number:</p>

    <p>If information displayed is incorrect, please email with corect details.</p>

    <div id="slider">

        <ul>

            <li><a href="#"><img src="Styles/images/slider/01.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>

            <li><a href="#"><img src="Styles/images/slider/02.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>

            <li><a href="#"><img src="Styles/images/slider/03.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>

            <li><a href="#"><img src="Styles/images/slider/04.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>

            <li><a href="#"><img src="Styles/images/slider/05.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>

        </ul>

    </div>

    </div>

    <div class="clear" />

    <div id="footer">

        <a id="FeedbackHyperLink" href="Feedback.aspx">Feedback</a> |

        <a id="ContactHyperLink" href="Contact.aspx">Contact us</a> |

        <a id="SitemapHyperLink" href="Sitemap.aspx">Sitemap</a> |

        <a id="HelpHyperLink" href="Help.aspx">Help</a>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you missing the CSS file?

Comment: The CSS file has been stated in the master file. I have tried adding it to this .aspx file but I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load jQuery before you load easySlider, so just change the order of the scripts:

From:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/easySlider1.7.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.js" ></script>
```

To:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/easySlider1.7.js"></script>
```

That  should do the trick :)

Answer (score 5):

Try referencing jquery-1.7.js first:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/easySlider1.7.js"></script>
```

Since easySlider1.7.js extends jquery and expects it to be already defined.

Anytime you use a jquery plugin(jquery UI or whatnot), remember to reference jquery first.  I looked at the examples for easySlider1.7, and the examples correctly references jquery first.  A good debugging technique to use is to start with what works, i.e. the examples, and try to find the differences between what works and what doesn't.  In this case the difference was that you referenced jquery after the plugin.

Comment: Thanks! This seemed to work. I will remember this from now on :)